# VBA to Combine Header with Subheaders in EXCEL?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub insertHeader()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("A2:AV2")

    For Each c1 In rng1
        If c1.Value <> "" Then
            c1.Value = c1.Offset(-1) & "_" & c1.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I am trying to combine the Header with Subheaders

See below pix-

Thanks in advance!![image: FIRST]

[image: Result]

Comment: What have you tried?  Posting the code you tried to implement but isn't working gives someone a direction on where your code is failing and therefore in a better position to assist you.

Comment: There is an easy-to-follow solution (which does not need VBA) that would require you to have an extra row on the spreadsheet and a dummy column on the left hand side, and the results presented on yet another row. If that's acceptable then I'll paste it up.

Comment: I gotta use VBA, I am trying to work on the code right now too. I am pretty new to VBA so its still a work in process. Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub insertHeader()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim currHeader

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("A2:AV2")
    currHeader = ""     

    For Each c1 In rng1
        If Len(c1.Offset(-1).Value)>0 Then
            currHeader = c1.Offset(-1).Value     
        End If
        If c1.Value <> "" & currHeader <> "" Then
            c1.Value = currHeader  & "_" & c1.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub insertHeader()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c1 As Range


Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng1 = ws.Range("A1:AV1")

For Each c1 In rng1
    If c1.Value <> "" Then
        c1.Offset(1, 0) = c1.Value & "_" & c1.Offset(1, 0)
        c1.Offset(1, 1) = c1.Value & "_" & c1.Offset(1, 1)
        c1.Offset(1, 2) = c1.Value & "_" & c1.Offset(1, 2)
        c1.Offset(1, 3) = c1.Value & "_" & c1.Offset(1, 3)
        c1.Offset(1, 4) = c1.Value & "_" & c1.Offset(1, 4)

    End If
Next


End Sub
```